# RESTful webservice with document style SOAP. Does it make sense?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

Does it work out to have a RESTful webservice using document style SOAP as messaging format ?

Comment: You cannot mix REST and SOAP they are completely different ways of doing things. I suspect you want to know if you can use XML as the protocol for a REST service? Yes you can. Normally this is done via JSON but nothing stops you from using XML.

Comment: Is not SOAP (next to the WSDL and UDDI stuff which is a different approach) also a "simple" protocol which says how things are encoded? Since XML lacks of a unique data encoding.

Comment: Actually we can use SOAP without using the RPC style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a passage in the book [SOA Expertenwissen](http://www.amazon.de/dp/3898644375) (page 403):

> "Es ist durchaus möglich, wenn auch unüblich, auch in einer REST-konformen Anwendung SOAP einzusetzen, um Nachrichten mit Header-Elementen für die Abbildung nichtfunktionaler Charakteristika anzureichern."

In English:

> It is possible but unusual to use SOAP in a REST compliant application. It is useful to include SOAP headers for providing non-functional information.